# I want to solve this error message 'FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.'

Tags: android, flutter

I've tried all of these, but nothing works.
1.flutter channel stable
flutter upgrade --force
flutter pub cache repair
cd 
flutter clean

2. elete your pubspec.lock, and press 'Pub Get' in your pubspec.yaml, it'll regenerate pubspec.lock file again and should fix the problem.
3. flutter clean
   flutter pub get

What should I do?

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.0.5, on macOS 12.5.1 21G83 darwin-x64, locale ko-KR)
• Flutter version 3.0.5 at /Users/iahyeon/Desktop/miracle/flutter
• Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
• Framework revision f1875d570e (7 weeks ago), 2022-07-13 11:24:16 -0700
• Engine revision e85ea0e79c
• Dart version 2.17.6
• DevTools version 2.12.2

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
    • Android SDK at /Users/iahyeon/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-31, build-tools 31.0.0
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.12+0-b1504.28-7817840)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✗] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
    ✗ Xcode installation is incomplete; a full installation is necessary for iOS development.
      Download at: https://developer.apple.com/xcode/download/
      Or install Xcode via the App Store.
      Once installed, run:
        sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
        sudo xcodebuild -runFirstLaunch
    ✗ CocoaPods not installed.
        CocoaPods is used to retrieve the iOS and macOS platform side's plugin code that
        responds to your plugin usage on the Dart side.
        Without CocoaPods, plugins will not work on iOS or macOS.
        For more info, see https://flutter.dev/platform-plugins
      To install see https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html#installation for
      instructions.

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.2)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.12+0-b1504.28-7817840)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.67.2)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension can be installed from:
       https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dart-Code.flutter

[✓] Connected device (3 available)
    • Android SDK built for x86 (mobile) • emulator-5554 • android-x86    • Android 8.1.0 (API
      27) (emulator)
    • macOS (desktop)                    • macos         • darwin-x64     • macOS 12.5.1 21G83
      darwin-x64
    • Chrome (web)                       • chrome        • web-javascript • Google Chrome
      104.0.5112.101

[✓] HTTP Host Availability
    • All required HTTP hosts are available
```

This is the result of flutter run -- verbose.

```
[ +212 ms] executing: sysctl hw.optional.arm64
[  +44 ms] Exit code 1 from: sysctl hw.optional.arm64
[   +2 ms] sysctl: unknown oid 'hw.optional.arm64'
[  +22 ms] executing: [/Users/iahyeon/Desktop/miracle/flutter/] git -c log.showSignature=false
log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H
[  +54 ms] Exit code 0 from: git -c log.showSignature=false log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H
[        ] f1875d570e39de09040c8f79aa13cc56baab8db1
[   +1 ms] executing: [/Users/iahyeon/Desktop/miracle/flutter/] git tag --points-at
f1875d570e39de09040c8f79aa13cc56baab8db1
[ +139 ms] Exit code 0 from: git tag --points-at f1875d570e39de09040c8f79aa13cc56baab8db1
[   +1 ms] 3.0.5
[  +21 ms] executing: [/Users/iahyeon/Desktop/miracle/flutter/] git rev-parse --abbrev-ref
--symbolic @{u}
[  +32 ms] Exit code 0 from: git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic @{u}
[        ] origin/stable
[        ] executing: [/Users/iahyeon/Desktop/miracle/flutter/] git ls-remote --get-url origin
[  +33 ms] Exit code 0 from: git ls-remote --get-url origin
[        ] https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
[ +222 ms] executing: [/Users/iahyeon/Desktop/miracle/flutter/] git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
[  +52 ms] Exit code 0 from: git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
[   +1 ms] stable
[  +26 ms] executing: sw_vers -productName
[  +40 ms] Exit code 0 from: sw_vers -productName
[        ] macOS
[        ] executing: sw_vers -productVersion
[  +31 ms] Exit code 0 from: sw_vers -productVersion
[        ] 12.5.1
[        ] executing: sw_vers -buildVersion
[  +35 ms] Exit code 0 from: sw_vers -buildVersion
[   +1 ms] 21G83
[        ] executing: uname -m
[  +13 ms] Exit code 0 from: uname -m
[        ] x86_64
[ +160 ms] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidGenSnapshotArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidInternalBuildArtifacts' is not required, skipping
update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'IOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterWebSdk' is not required, skipping update.
[   +7 ms] Artifact Instance of 'WindowsEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'WindowsUwpEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerDebugSymbols' is not required, skipping update.
[ +125 ms] executing: /Users/iahyeon/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb devices -l
[  +25 ms] executing: sysctl hw.optional.arm64
[  +10 ms] Exit code 1 from: sysctl hw.optional.arm64
[   +1 ms] sysctl: unknown oid 'hw.optional.arm64'
[        ] executing: xcrun xcodebuild -version
[  +15 ms] Exit code 72 from: xcrun xcodebuild -version
[   +1 ms] xcrun: error: unable to find utility "xcodebuild", not a developer tool or in PATH
[   +1 ms] Xcode not found. Run 'flutter doctor' for more information.
[   +4 ms] executing: xcrun xcodebuild -version
[  +16 ms] Exit code 72 from: xcrun xcodebuild -version
[   +2 ms] xcrun: error: unable to find utility "xcodebuild", not a developer tool or in PATH
[  +12 ms] executing: xcrun xcodebuild -version
[  +17 ms] Exit code 72 from: xcrun xcodebuild -version
[        ] xcrun: error: unable to find utility "xcodebuild", not a developer tool or in PATH
[  +85 ms] List of devices attached
           emulator-5554          device product:sdk_gphone_x86 model:Android_SDK_built_for_x86
           device:generic_x86 transport_id:1
[  +21 ms] /Users/iahyeon/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5554 shell getprop
[  +84 ms] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidInternalBuildArtifacts' is not required, skipping
update.
[   +1 ms] Artifact Instance of 'IOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +6 ms] Artifact Instance of 'WindowsEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'WindowsUwpEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[  +10 ms] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +3 ms] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerDebugSymbols' is not required, skipping update.
[  +66 ms] executing: xcrun xcodebuild -version
[  +13 ms] Exit code 72 from: xcrun xcodebuild -version
[        ] xcrun: error: unable to find utility "xcodebuild", not a developer tool or in PATH
[ +254 ms] Running "flutter pub get" in miracle...
[   +8 ms] Using /Users/iahyeon/Desktop/miracle/flutter/.pub-cache for the pub cache.
[   +2 ms] executing: [/Users/iahyeon/Desktop/miracle/miracle/]
/Users/iahyeon/Desktop/miracle/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin/dart __deprecated_pub --verbose
get --no-precompile
[ +199 ms] FINE: Pub 2.17.6
[ +138 ms] MSG : Resolving dependencies...
[  +94 ms] SLVR: fact: miracle is 1.0.0+1
[  +19 ms] SLVR: derived: miracle
[  +62 ms] SLVR: fact: miracle depends on flutter from sdk
[   +1 ms] SLVR: fact: miracle depends on carousel_slider any
[        ] SLVR: fact: miracle depends on cupertino_icons ^1.0.2
[        ] SLVR: fact: miracle depends on flutter_test from sdk
[   +3 ms] SLVR: fact: miracle depends on flutter_lints ^2.0.0
[   +7 ms] SLVR:   selecting miracle
[        ] SLVR:   derived: flutter_lints ^2.0.0
[        ] SLVR:   derived: flutter_test from sdk
[        ] SLVR:   derived: cupertino_icons ^1.0.2
[        ] SLVR:   derived: carousel_slider any
[   +1 ms] SLVR:   derived: flutter from sdk
[  +39 ms] SLVR:   fact: flutter_lints 2.0.1 depends on lints ^2.0.0
[   +1 ms] SLVR:     selecting flutter_lints 2.0.1
[        ] SLVR:     derived: lints ^2.0.0
[  +13 ms] SLVR:     fact: flutter_test 0.0.0 from sdk depends on flutter from sdk
[        ] SLVR:     fact: flutter_test 0.0.0 from sdk depends on test_api 0.4.9
[        ] SLVR:     fact: flutter_test 0.0.0 from sdk depends on path 1.8.1
[        ] SLVR:     fact: flutter_test 0.0.0 from sdk depends on fake_async 1.3.0
[        ] SLVR:     fact: flutter_test 0.0.0 from sdk depends on clock 1.1.0
[        ] SLVR:     fact: flutter_test 0.0.0 from sdk depends on stack_trace 1.10.0
[        ] SLVR:     fact: flutter_test 0.0.0 from sdk depends on vector_math 2.1.2
[        ] SLVR:     fact: flutter_test 0.0.0 from sdk depends on async 2.8.2
[        ] SLVR:     fact: flutter_test 0.0.0 from sdk depends on boolean_selector 2.1.0
[   +1 ms] SLVR:     fact: flutter_test 0.0.0 from sdk depends on characters 1.2.0
[        ] SLVR:     fact: flutter_test 0.0.0 from sdk depends on charcode 1.3.1
[        ] SLVR:     fact: flutter_test 0.0.0 from sdk depends on collection 1.16.0
[        ] SLVR:     fact: flutter_test 0.0.0 from sdk depends on matcher 0.12.11
[        ] SLVR:     fact: flutter_test 0.0.0 from sdk depends on material_color_utilities 0.1.4
[        ] SLVR:     fact: flutter_test 0.0.0 from sdk depends on meta 1.7.0
[   +2 ms] SLVR:     fact: flutter_test 0.0.0 from sdk depends on source_span 1.8.2
[   +1 ms] SLVR:     fact: flutter_test 0.0.0 from sdk depends on stream_channel 2.1.0
[        ] SLVR:     fact: flutter_test 0.0.0 from sdk depends on string_scanner 1.1.0
[        ] SLVR:     fact: flutter_test 0.0.0 from sdk depends on term_glyph 1.2.0
[        ] SLVR:       selecting flutter_test 0.0.0 from sdk
[        ] SLVR:       derived: term_glyph 1.2.0
[   +1 ms] SLVR:       derived: string_scanner 1.1.0
[        ] SLVR:       derived: stream_channel 2.1.0
[        ] SLVR:       derived: source_span 1.8.2
[        ] SLVR:       derived: meta 1.7.0
[        ] SLVR:       derived: material_color_utilities 0.1.4
[        ] SLVR:       derived: matcher 0.12.11
[        ] SLVR:       derived: collection 1.16.0
[        ] SLVR:       derived: charcode 1.3.1
[        ] SLVR:       derived: characters 1.2.0
[        ] SLVR:       derived: boolean_selector 2.1.0
[        ] SLVR:       derived: async 2.8.2
[        ] SLVR:       derived: vector_math 2.1.2
[        ] SLVR:       derived: stack_trace 1.10.0
[        ] SLVR:       derived: clock 1.1.0
[        ] SLVR:       derived: fake_async 1.3.0
[        ] SLVR:       derived: path 1.8.1
[        ] SLVR:       derived: test_api 0.4.9
[  +23 ms] SLVR:         selecting cupertino_icons 1.0.5
[   +8 ms] SLVR:         fact: carousel_slider 4.1.1 depends on flutter from sdk
[        ] SLVR:           selecting carousel_slider 4.1.1
[  +16 ms] SLVR:           fact: flutter 0.0.0 from sdk depends on characters 1.2.0
[        ] SLVR:           fact: flutter 0.0.0 from sdk depends on collection 1.16.0
[        ] SLVR:           fact: flutter 0.0.0 from sdk depends on material_color_utilities
0.1.4
[        ] SLVR:           fact: flutter 0.0.0 from sdk depends on meta 1.7.0
[        ] SLVR:           fact: flutter 0.0.0 from sdk depends on vector_math 2.1.2
[        ] SLVR:           fact: flutter 0.0.0 from sdk depends on sky_engine from sdk
[        ] SLVR:             selecting flutter 0.0.0 from sdk
[        ] SLVR:             derived: sky_engine from sdk
[  +13 ms] SLVR:               selecting lints 2.0.0
[   +9 ms] SLVR:                 selecting term_glyph 1.2.0
[  +14 ms] SLVR:                 fact: string_scanner 1.1.0 depends on charcode ^1.2.0
[   +1 ms] SLVR:                 fact: string_scanner 1.1.0 depends on source_span ^1.8.0
[   +1 ms] SLVR:                   selecting string_scanner 1.1.0
[  +18 ms] SLVR:                   fact: stream_channel 2.1.0 depends on async ^2.5.0
[        ] SLVR:                     selecting stream_channel 2.1.0
[   +9 ms] SLVR:                     fact: source_span 1.8.2 depends on collection ^1.15.0
[   +1 ms] SLVR:                     fact: source_span 1.8.2 depends on path ^1.8.0
[   +2 ms] SLVR:                     fact: source_span 1.8.2 depends on term_glyph ^1.2.0
[        ] SLVR:                       selecting source_span 1.8.2
[   +9 ms] SLVR:                         selecting meta 1.7.0
[  +12 ms] SLVR:                           selecting material_color_utilities 0.1.4
[  +14 ms] SLVR:                           fact: matcher 0.12.11 depends on stack_trace ^1.10.0
[   +2 ms] SLVR:                             selecting matcher 0.12.11
[  +12 ms] SLVR:                               selecting collection 1.16.0
[   +8 ms] SLVR:                                 selecting charcode 1.3.1
[  +13 ms] SLVR:                                   selecting characters 1.2.0
[   +3 ms] SLVR:                                   fact: boolean_selector 2.1.0 depends on
source_span ^1.8.0
[   +2 ms] SLVR:                                   fact: boolean_selector 2.1.0 depends on
string_scanner ^1.1.0
[   +1 ms] SLVR:                                     selecting boolean_selector 2.1.0
[   +7 ms] SLVR:                                     fact: async 2.8.2 depends on collection
^1.15.0
[   +1 ms] SLVR:                                     fact: async 2.8.2 depends on meta ^1.1.7
[        ] SLVR:                                       selecting async 2.8.2
[   +8 ms] SLVR:                                         selecting vector_math 2.1.2
[   +5 ms] SLVR:                                         fact: stack_trace 1.10.0 depends on
path ^1.8.0
[   +1 ms] SLVR:                                           selecting stack_trace 1.10.0
[   +7 ms] SLVR:                                             selecting clock 1.1.0
[   +9 ms] SLVR:                                             fact: fake_async 1.3.0 depends on
clock ^1.1.0
[   +1 ms] SLVR:                                             fact: fake_async 1.3.0 depends on
collection ^1.15.0
[        ] SLVR:                                               selecting fake_async 1.3.0
[  +16 ms] SLVR:                                                 selecting path 1.8.1
[   +2 ms] SLVR:                                                 fact: test_api 0.4.9 depends on
async ^2.5.0
[   +7 ms] SLVR:                                                 fact: test_api 0.4.9 depends on
boolean_selector ^2.1.0
[  +17 ms] SLVR:                                                 fact: test_api 0.4.9 depends on
collection ^1.15.0
[  +19 ms] SLVR:                                                 fact: test_api 0.4.9 depends on
meta ^1.3.0
[   +1 ms] SLVR:                                                 fact: test_api 0.4.9 depends on
source_span ^1.8.0
[  +10 ms] SLVR:                                                 fact: test_api 0.4.9 depends on
stack_trace ^1.10.0
[   +2 ms] SLVR:                                                 fact: test_api 0.4.9 depends on
stream_channel ^2.1.0
[   +1 ms] SLVR:                                                 fact: test_api 0.4.9 depends on
string_scanner ^1.1.0
[        ] SLVR:                                                 fact: test_api 0.4.9 depends on
term_glyph ^1.2.0
[   +1 ms] SLVR:                                                 fact: test_api 0.4.9 depends on
matcher >=0.12.11 <0.12.12
[        ] SLVR:                                                   selecting test_api 0.4.9
[        ] SLVR:                                                     selecting sky_engine 0.0.99
from sdk
[ +315 ms] SLVR: Version solving took 0:00:00.829774 seconds.
[        ]     | Tried 1 solutions.
[   +4 ms] FINE: Resolving dependencies finished (0.925s).
[  +27 ms] MSG :   async 2.8.2 (2.9.0 available)
[        ]     |   characters 1.2.0 (1.2.1 available)
[        ]     |   clock 1.1.0 (1.1.1 available)
[        ]     |   fake_async 1.3.0 (1.3.1 available)
[        ]     |   matcher 0.12.11 (0.12.12 available)
[        ]     |   material_color_utilities 0.1.4 (0.2.0 available)
[        ]     |   meta 1.7.0 (1.8.0 available)
[        ]     |   path 1.8.1 (1.8.2 available)
[        ]     |   source_span 1.8.2 (1.9.1 available)
[        ]     |   string_scanner 1.1.0 (1.1.1 available)
[        ]     |   term_glyph 1.2.0 (1.2.1 available)
[        ]     |   test_api 0.4.9 (0.4.13 available)
[        ]     |   vector_math 2.1.2 (2.1.3 available)
[  +87 ms] IO  : Writing 3956 characters to text file pubspec.lock.
[        ] FINE: Contents:
[   +1 ms]     | # Generated by pub
[        ]     | # See https://dart.dev/tools/pub/glossary#lockfile
[        ]     | packages:
[        ]     |   async:
[        ]     |     dependency: transitive
[        ]     |     description:
[        ]     |       name: async
[        ]     |       url: "https://pub.dartlang.org"
[   +1 ms]     |     source: hosted
[        ]     |     version: "2.8.2"
[        ]     |   boolean_selector:
[        ]     |     dependency: transitive
[        ]     |     description:
[        ]     |       name: boolean_selector
[        ]     |       url: "https://pub.dartlang.org"
[        ]     |     source: hosted
[        ]     |     version: "2.1.0"
[        ]     |   carousel_slider:
[   +1 ms]     |     dependency: "direct main"
[        ]     |     description:
[        ]     |       name: carousel_slider
[        ]     |       url: "https://pub.dartlang.org"
[        ]     |     source: hosted
[        ]     |     version: "4.1.1"
[        ]     |   characters:
[   +2 ms]     |     dependency: transitive
[        ]     |     description:
[   +4 ms]     |       name: characters
[        ]     |       url: "https://pub.dartlang.org"
[   +2 ms]     |     source: hosted
[        ]     |     version: "1.2.0"
[        ]     |   charcode:
[        ]     |     dependency: transitive
[        ]     |     description:
[        ]     |       name: charcode
[        ]     |       url: "https://pub.dartlang.org"
[        ]     |     source: hosted
[   +1 ms]     |     version: "1.3.1"
[        ]     |   clock:
[        ]     |     dependency: transitive
[        ]     |     description:
[   +1 ms]     |       name: clock
[        ]     |       url: "https://pub.dartlang.org"
[        ]     |     source: hosted
[        ]     |     version: "1.1.0"
[        ]     |   collection:
[        ]     |     dependency: transitive
[        ]     |     description:
[        ]     |       name: collection
[        ]     |       url: "https://pub.dartlang.org"
[        ]     |     source: hosted
[        ]     |     version: "1.16.0"
[        ]     |   cupertino_icons:
[        ]     |     dependency: "direct main"
[        ]     |     description:
[        ]     |       name: cupertino_icons
[   +6 ms]     |       url: "https://pub.dartlang.org"
[   +1 ms]     |     source: hosted
[        ]     |     version: "1.0.5"
[        ]     |   fake_async:
[        ]     |     dependency: transitive
[        ]     |     description:
[        ]     |       name: fake_async
[        ]     |       url: "https://pub.dartlang.org"
[        ]     |     source: hosted
[        ]     |     version: "1.3.0"
[        ]     |   flutter:
[        ]     |     dependency: "direct main"
[        ]     |     description: flutter
[        ]     |     source: sdk
[        ]     |     version: "0.0.0"
[        ]     |   flutter_lints:
[        ]     |     dependency: "direct dev"
[        ]     |     description:
[        ]     |       name: flutter_lints
[        ]     |       url: "https://pub.dartlang.org"
[        ]     |     source: hosted
[        ]     |     version: "2.0.1"
[  +11 ms]     |   flutter_test:
[        ]     |     dependency: "direct dev"
[        ]     |     description: flutter
[        ]     |     source: sdk
[        ]     |     version: "0.0.0"
[        ]     |   lints:
[        ]     |     dependency: transitive
[        ]     |     description:
[        ]     |       name: lints
[        ]     |       url: "https://pub.dartlang.org"
[        ]     |     source: hosted
[        ]     |     version: "2.0.0"
[        ]     |   matcher:
[        ]     |     dependency: transitive
[        ]     |     description:
[        ]     |       name: matcher
[        ]     |       url: "https://pub.dartlang.org"
[        ]     |     source: hosted
[        ]     |     version: "0.12.11"
[        ]     |   material_color_utilities:
[        ]     |     dependency: transitive
[        ]     |     description:
[        ]     |       name: material_color_utilities
[        ]     |       url: "https://pub.dartlang.org"
[        ]     |     source: hosted
[   +3 ms]     |     version: "0.1.4"
[        ]     |   meta:
[        ]     |     dependency: transitive
[        ]     |     description:
[        ]     |       name: meta
[        ]     |       url: "https://pub.dartlang.org"
[        ]     |     source: hosted
[        ]     |     version: "1.7.0"
[        ]     |   path:
[        ]     |     dependency: transitive
[        ]     |     description:
[        ]     |       name: path
[        ]     |       url: "https://pub.dartlang.org"
[        ]     |     source: hosted
[        ]     |     version: "1.8.1"
[        ]     |   sky_engine:
[        ]     |     dependency: transitive
[   +1 ms]     |     description: flutter
[        ]     |     source: sdk
[   +3 ms]     |     version: "0.0.99"
[   +1 ms]     |   source_span:
[        ]     |     dependency: transitive
[        ]     |     description:
[        ]     |       name: source_span
[        ]     |       url: "https://pub.dartlang.org"
[        ]     |     source: hosted
[        ]     |     version: "1.8.2"
[        ]     |   stack_trace:
[        ]     |     dependency: transitive
[        ]     |     description:
[        ]     |       name: stack_trace
[        ]     |       url: "https://pub.dartlang.org"
[        ]     |     source: hosted
[        ]     |     version: "1.10.0"
[        ]     |   stream_channel:
[        ]     |     dependency: transitive
[        ]     |     description:
[        ]     |       name: stream_channel
[        ]     |       url: "https://pub.dartlang.org"
[        ]     |     source: hosted
[        ]     |     version: "2.1.0"
[        ]     |   string_scanner:
[        ]     |     dependency: transitive
[        ]     |     description:
[        ]     |       name: string_scanner
[        ]     |       url: "https://pub.dartlang.org"
[        ]     |     source: hosted
[        ]     |     version: "1.1.0"
[        ]     |   term_glyph:
[        ]     |     dependency: transitive
[        ]     |     description:
[        ]     |       name: term_glyph
[        ]     |       url: "https://pub.dartlang.org"
[        ]     |     source: hosted
[        ]     |     version: "1.2.0"
[        ]     |   test_api:
[        ]     |     dependency: transitive
[        ]     |     description:
[        ]     |       name: test_api
[        ]     |       url: "https://pub.dartlang.org"
[        ]     |     source: hosted
[        ]     |     version: "0.4.9"
[        ]     |   vector_math:
[        ]     |     dependency: transitive
[        ]     |     description:
[        ]     |       name: vector_math
[   +5 ms]     |       url: "https://pub.dartlang.org"
[        ]     |     source: hosted
[        ]     |     version: "2.1.2"
[        ]     | sdks:
[        ]     |   dart: ">=2.17.6 <3.0.0"
[   +3 ms] IO  : Writing 3009 characters to text file .packages.
[   +1 ms] FINE: Contents:
[        ]     | # This file is deprecated. Tools should instead consume 
[        ]     | # `.dart_tool/package_config.json`.
[        ]     | # 
[        ]     | # For more info see: https://dart.dev/go/dot-packages-deprecation
[        ]     | # 
[        ]     | # Generated by pub on 2022-08-30 23:09:40.982459.
[        ]     |
async:file:///Users/iahyeon/Desktop/miracle/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/async-2.8
.2/lib/
[   +3 ms]     |
boolean_selector:file:///Users/iahyeon/Desktop/miracle/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.or
g/boolean_selector-2.1.0/lib/
[   +1 ms]     |
carousel_slider:file:///Users/iahyeon/Desktop/miracle/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org
/carousel_slider-4.1.1/lib/
[   +1 ms]     |
characters:file:///Users/iahyeon/Desktop/miracle/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/char
acters-1.2.0/lib/
[        ]     |
charcode:file:///Users/iahyeon/Desktop/miracle/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/charco
de-1.3.1/lib/
[   +3 ms]     |
clock:file:///Users/iahyeon/Desktop/miracle/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/clock-1.1
.0/lib/
[        ]     |

collection:file:///Users/iahyeon/Desktop/miracle/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/coll
ection-1.16.0/lib/
[        ]     |
cupertino_icons:file:///Users/iahyeon/Desktop/miracle/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org
/cupertino_icons-1.0.5/lib/
[   +3 ms]     |
fake_async:file:///Users/iahyeon/Desktop/miracle/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fake
_async-1.3.0/lib/
[   +1 ms]     | flutter:file:///Users/iahyeon/Desktop/miracle/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/
[        ]     |
flutter_lints:file:///Users/iahyeon/Desktop/miracle/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/f
lutter_lints-2.0.1/lib/
[        ]     |
flutter_test:file:///Users/iahyeon/Desktop/miracle/flutter/packages/flutter_test/lib/
[        ]     |
lints:file:///Users/iahyeon/Desktop/miracle/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/lints-2.0
.0/lib/
[        ]     |
matcher:file:///Users/iahyeon/Desktop/miracle/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/matcher
-0.12.11/lib/
[   +1 ms]     |
material_color_utilities:file:///Users/iahyeon/Desktop/miracle/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dar
tlang.org/material_color_utilities-0.1.4/lib/
[   +3 ms]     |
meta:file:///Users/iahyeon/Desktop/miracle/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/meta-1.7.0
/lib/
[   +1 ms]     |
```

Comment: did you try with `flutter clean`, `flutter create .`

Answer (score 0):

You are running your flutter app on an iOS device or simulator, but you do not have the required software installed. You will ned to

- install Xcode
- install Cocoapods

This issue and the installation instruction can also be found via `flutter doctor`

```
[✗] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
    ✗ Xcode installation is incomplete; a full installation is necessary for iOS development.
      Download at: https://developer.apple.com/xcode/download/
      Or install Xcode via the App Store.
      Once installed, run:
        sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
        sudo xcodebuild -runFirstLaunch
    ✗ CocoaPods not installed.
        CocoaPods is used to retrieve the iOS and macOS platform side's plugin code that
        responds to your plugin usage on the Dart side.
        Without CocoaPods, plugins will not work on iOS or macOS.
        For more info, see https://flutter.dev/platform-plugins
      To install see https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html#installation for
      instructions.
```